# ios : Mute Button doesn't work after application enters foreground

Tags: ios, xcode, button, foreground, mute

I've created a button that stops and plays background music when clicked. It works great, but when I click on the home button, and relaunch the application (background - foreground) the button doesn't work. I click on it and it does nothing. Help please!! Thanks

This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)muteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIImage *currentImage = [self.muteButton currentImage];
    UIImage *vol1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Volume 1"];
    UIImage *vol2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Volume 2"];
    if ([currentImage isEqual:vol1]) {
    [self.muteButton setImage:vol2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.backgroundMusic stop];
    self.scene.playSounds = NO;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"playSounds"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    }
    if ([currentImage isEqual:vol2]) {
    [self.muteButton setImage:vol1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self playBackground];
    self.scene.playSounds = YES;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"playSounds"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

and this is the code in the viewcontroller :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *playSoundsString = [defaults objectForKey:@"playSounds"];
NSInteger playSoundsInt = [playSoundsString intValue];
NSNumber *playSoundsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:playSoundsInt];
self.scene.playSounds = [playSoundsNumber boolValue];

if (self.scene.playSounds == YES) {
UIImage *vol1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Volume 1"];
self.scene.playSounds = YES;
[self playBackground];
[self.muteButton setImage:vol1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (self.scene.playSounds == NO) {
UIImage *vol2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Volume 2"];
self.scene.playSounds = NO;
[self.muteButton setImage:vol2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

finally this is when my app enters background (in viewcontroller) :

```
if (self.scene.playSounds == YES) {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopMusic:) name:@"SOUND_OFF" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It'll be much easier for someone to answer your question if you can provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org). That is, please provide the code that's causing the problem, or that isn't working as you intend.

Comment: You may find it helpful to insert a breakpoint where you think the method should be called to see what's happening as the program runs.

Comment: Okay, I've entered the code

Comment: Also, the problem is not when the app is running, it's when I go background, and re-enter the app